# How to export an Eclipse project (with LWJGL) for execution

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, executable-jar

I have created a 3D game engine in Eclipse with java, using LWJGL, Slick-Util, and PNGDecoder. However, anytime that I try to export it so I can run it on a computer without Eclipse, it fails to work. You can see the code at https://www.github.com/WickedJet/jEngineX-1.28. All of the eclipse export options, i have indeed tried, and I've also tried to use JarSplice and One-Jar, both of which seem to not work for me.

Comment: You should be a little more specific than *it fails to work*

Comment: Sorry. When i try to run the "executable jar" the LWJGL window flickers for a second, then crashes, and says it cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all you dependencies are copied into the build path.

Then right-click the project and export as a 'runnable jar'.